# Finding the first subarray that sums to a given total

Tags: array, complexity, big-o

Here is the question:

> Given and unordered array of positive and negative integers. How can you find the first subarray to sum to a given value?

For example. Given the array...

```
[1, -3, 4, 8, 2, -14, 3, -1, 10, 6]
```

Find the first subarray to sum to 9.

In this example the sub array would be...

```
[-3, 4, 8]
```

I found a solution that is O(n^2) by iterating the array for start points and then iterating every end point until you find the value.

But is there a way to do this better than O(n^2)?

Comment: Well, you only need one pass.  You can skip any value that exceeds the target sum, and your inner loop can terminate when the candidate sum exceeds the target sum without equaling it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if the total value of the array was less than the sum then that would keep going for the whole rest of the array from every start point wouldn't it? Also, I don't think that would work for number 2.

Comment: Hold on, I'm writing an answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ok :-) also, I fixed your edit. It was "Then I" not "They".

Comment: How can you come up with an O(N) solution, but then say you couldn't better the O(N^2) solution?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't say that. :-)

Comment: Read your question again.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yup, I didn't say that.

Comment: Well, negative numbers shouldn't make any difference.  A sum is a sum.

Comment: @RobertHarvey negative numbers makes a huge difference. For instance a subarray total of 10 for an array of [500, 500, -990].

Comment: So? .............

Comment: @RobertHarvey your initial comment would skip the first two values because they are greater than total.

Comment: Oh, I see.  They claim to have an O(n) solution for that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey they didn't comment on what they had for that. I managed to come up with the n squared solution for it but wondered if anyone here could better it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think so.  It's like the interviewer who asked me to write a string reverser.  I did so, in C#, using a StringBuilder; it was O(n).  They asked me if I could improve the Big O.  I told them you could employ some sort of divide and conquer algorithm, but you'd still have to touch every character; the StringBuilder was already the fastest possible way.  The same is true here; you'd still have to touch every array element at least once, probably several times.

Comment: By the way, Googling the title of your question comes up with tons of help.  Apparently this question is not a novel one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ok cool thanks. Yeah, they asked if I could improve and I said no because you'd have to check every value from every start point until you hit the total. Thanks, will google now :-)

Comment: Technically it relies on te technique called [prefix sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum).

Comment: Your question is confusing... Did you come up with an O(n) solution? If so, I think you're good. It's highly unlikely you'll find an O(log n) solution given the nature of the problem. You should edit your question to ask for an O(log n) solution, or to ask for a proof one is not possible. This would make the question more clear. If you want an O(n) solution, just ask for that and someone will surely post a pseudo-code algorithm, I can think of a worst-case O(n) solution myself.

Comment: Here's a simple O(n) solution I figured off hand: https://dotnetfiddle.net/D88a8C - Short of concurrency I don't think you're going to improve over O(n)..

Comment: @JimmyHoffa if you don't understand a question then you shouldn't be editing it. Especially when you deleted pretty much half of it.

Comment: There is something wrong with your question.  First you say "I managed to come up with an answer that was O(n).".  Then you say "Again my solution was O(n^2) and I couldn't better it.".  Which is it?  The best case algorithm for this is O(n).  If you achieved that, then you are done.  If you did not, then this question needs editing.

Comment: @StevenBurnap yes. That's because they introduced the negative numbers to the problem. That changes the whole problem. If you look through the comments you can see this discussion.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa there are no negative numbers in that example. Deleting that section of the question doesn't make it go away. The second part of the problem was about negative numbers in the array.

Comment: Tbh. The comments I'm getting on this are evidence that people really have no clue that negative numbers completely change the problem. The reason the second solution is n^2 is because negative numbers are introduced. It is a different problem. If you think it isn't then I suggest trying it out.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, it changes the problem, but still, an O(n) algorithm exists.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem .  The trouble was that your question was badly written and made it sound like you already had an O(n) algorithm.  (The original question, before any edits.)

Comment: @StevenBurnap I'm not sure that method would work for finding a subarray with a given sum though would it?

Comment: @StevenBurnap yep, after reading through again I'm confident that that link will not solve this problem. I've edited the question now. (Well, not really, it's still the same question just with fewer words). Would appreciate it being taken off hold now. Thanks

Comment: Off hand I think [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CxBWCs) is O(n log n) unless I'm not thinking about it clearly, and it works with negatives.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa thanks. That's the solution I can up with. I think that's n^2 as you are iterating n-1 numbers then n-2 then n-3 all the way to 2 then 1. That sum is n(n-1)/2 which is n^2.

Comment: What have you tried, how are you sure it's possible? You put many constraints: Subarray, Negative numbers, sum up to a certain number... I think you should check all subarrays and that is O (n^2)

Comment: @Ahmad I don't think there are many constraints. And if you remove one then the question isn't valid. Lol. It has gone from being too broad to being too constrained and I haven't actually changed the question. :-) This is something I was asked in an interview and I cam up with the n^2 solution but they asked how could I improve it. I said I couldn't.

Comment: How are you defining the first subarray? [1, -3, 4, 8, 1, -14, 3, -1, 10] adds up to 9 and starts before the expected answer listed in the question.

Comment: @Sign sorry, you're right. He first is the one that starts first. Bad example writing on my part. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

- We run through the array, computing the sums of all the prefixes along the way. (O(n) since we can keep a running tally of the sum)
- We save the sums we encounter in some datastructure where we can search by the value of the sum and also get prefix that the sum belongs to (see below for implementation of this)
- If the sum of the prefix up to index n is off target by an amount that is the sum of a prefix we previously encountered, say, up to index m, then we found our subarray, the array from m to n. Since `sum(prefix(n)) - sum(prefix(m)) = targetSum` and `subArray(m,n) = prefix(n) - prefix(m)` (hopefully this psuedo-notation is somewhat clear)

Now the running time of our algorithm is `n * (the time it takes to insert the sum of our prefix to the datastructure + the time it takes to search if we have a certain sum in our datastructure)`.

An obvious choice for a datastructure would be a [hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) with sums as keys and the prefix they are the sum of as values. Here search and insert take O(1) on average, so we would be O(n) on average, which seems rather decent. Code could be:

```java
public int[] findSubArray(int[] arr, int targetSum){
    Map<Integer, Integer> sumsToIndex = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int sum = 0;

    for(int index = 0; index <= arr.length; index++){
        if(sumsToIndex.get(sum) == null){
            sumsToIndex.put(sum, index);
        }

        int offTarget = sum - targetSum;
        Integer offTargetPrefix = sumsToIndex.get(offTarget);
        if(offTargetPrefix != null){
            return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, offTargetPrefix, index);
        }

        if(index < arr.length){
            sum += arr[index];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

However worst case, search in a hashtable is O(n) if we get a boatload of collisions, I don't know how this pans out here. Since our keys are integers, I think we might be okay. But maybe theoretically we are still O(n) worst case. Making our algorithm O(n^2) still.

What we could do is use some other datastructure, like [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) (with the sums as sorting key), where search and insertion are O(log n) in the worst case, making our algorithm O(n log(n)).

Comment: Ok. So we store the sum total up to each index. And store it as a key value pair with the sum total as the key and the index as the value. Then if we are at say value 100 and we try to get the value for the key 90 then we know it has a subarray with sum 10.

Comment: Yes, thats the idea (and np obv, liked the problem)

Comment: It's actually similar to an idea I came up with in the interview but I didn't store the running totals in a hash to look them up. I stored them in an array but then it was n^2 to find too with the correct difference.

Comment: @Fogmeister I googled the problem and found a similar problem and solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865688/subsequence-sum, according to that I think it should be `return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, offTargetPrefix + 1, index);`, Moreover, as you look for the first sub-array, I think if we encounter a collision we should keep the old index and don't update it, this way, the complexity would remain `O(n)`

Comment: @Ahmad yes I thought this too. Because you're looking for the first then if the previous sum exists then don't change it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I came up with a solution. Suppose the following numbers, and you want to find the first subarray to sum to 4:

```
2 -3 7 1 5 -1
```

First to get rid of negative numbers, I suggest find the smallest number (-3) and add its absolute value to all the numbers, that takes `O(n)`, we have:

```
5  0  10 4  8 2
```

Then for any sub-array with size n, the sum should be `n*3 + 4`, if you find that sum, then you have found the answer

I wrote the target for the sub-arrays with size 1, 2, 3 ...

```
7   10  13  16   19
```

Now start with 5, it is less than 7 then you can continue, add it to 0, it is less than 10, and you can continue, add it to 10, it is more than 13, then ignore 5, and regard 0 + 10, it is less than 10, actually it is equal to 10, it means you have found the answer, the answer is -3 + 7 = 4

---

I try to write the algorithm down! ,

```
 SubArraySumTo(A[], y)
 {
     x = abs(min(A));  // a loop over the array
     foreach (var a in A)
     {
         a+=x;
     }
     int start =0;
     int sum =A[0];
     int i=0;
     while (i < n)
     {
         target = (i - start +1)*x + y;              
         if (sum == target)
         {
              return A[start..i];
         }
         else if (sum < target)
         {
            i++; 
            sum += A[i];
         }
         else if (sum > target)
         {
             start++;
             sum -= A[start];
         }
     }
 }
```

It's an iteration with O(2n) in worst case

Comment: Ah. I like that. So it is essentially O(2n) which is just n. By removing the negative numbers you've changed it to the simpler version of dealing just with non negative integers.

Comment: Your welcome, I didn't test it much! you can test it with your sequences, I hope it works! ironically I was the one who just already said it can't be solved simply :)

Comment: Not sure this works. Try and find the sum "400" in O(n) given this list: -1 -4 -90 -2 -22 -44 -1231 -1 -1 -900 -4 500 -100

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Oh! that is a big list and with big numbers, (the step here is 1231) could you give your point with small numbers?  I think the algorithm should work for any list. What you expect and what it returns?

Comment: @Fogmeister I tried to write the idea down, its O(2n) which is O(n), please try to implement it if it works or not!

Comment: I think this doesnt work. In the non-negative case we can solve like "if the subarray sum is too large we cant get anywhere by adding to the end, so we remove at the start. If the subarray sum is too small, we need to add more at the end". This tries to reduce to that using the trick of getting rid of the negatives. But the reasoning still breaks down.

Comment: Ex. find 1 in [2,-1]. Naively, after seeing [2], we wont try to add since 2 is already too large. That's wrong, our sum will get smaller if we add more. Now your trick. We add 1 to everything and transform to [3,0]. We see [3] and match to the new target, 2. Too large, so we wont try adding more. Still wrong. Only now its not because our sum will get smaller, but because our target will get bigger (faster than our sum will get bigger) if we add more.

Comment: @Hirle, you are right, I turn back to my previous statement, that the constraints are too much to be satisfied simply ;) !

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a sum s, and the total of all array elements is t, then the sum of the first i and the last j elements must be t - s, so the elements from index i to index n-j exclusive add up to s.

So you create a hash table or a balanced binary tree for the sum of the last j elements, starting with j = 0, then adding another element for j = 1, 2, 3 etc. Hash table will be O (1) on average, but balanced binary tree is O (log n) worst case.

For each j, you check whether t minus s minus the sum of the first i = n-j elements is in the hash table or binary tree, and proceed until j = n and i = 0.

O (n) average using a hash table, but no guarantee for the worst case. O (n log n) if you use a balanced search tree.

As an example with the data [1, -3, 4, 8, 2, -14, 3, -1, 10, 6]: The total is t = 16, we were given s = 9, so the sum of the first i and the last j elements must be 7. The list of sums of the last j elements are:

```
j = 0: 0
j = 1: 0, 6
j = 2: 0, 6, 16
j = 3: 0, 6, 16, 15
j = 4: 0, 6, 16, 15, 18
j = 5: 0, 6, 16, 15, 18, 4
j = 6: 0, 6, 16, 15, 18, 4, 6
j = 7: 0, 6, 16, 15, 18, 4, 6, 14
j = 8: 0, 6, 16, 15, 18, 4, 6, 14, 18
j = 9: 0, 6, 16, 15, 18, 4, 6, 14, 18, 15
j = 10: 0, 6, 16, 15, 18, 4, 6, 14, 18, 15, 16
```

Then we calculate the sum of the first i = 10-j elements, and 7 minus that sum must be in the last of the sums of the last j elements.

```
j =  0, i = 10: 7 -  16 = -9, not found
j =  1, i =  9: 7 -  10 = -3, not found
j =  2, i =  8: 7 -   0 =  7, not found
j =  3, i =  7: 7 -   1 =  6, found
j =  4, i =  6: 7 - (-2) = 9, not found
j =  5, i =  5: 7 -  12 = -5, not found
j =  6, i =  4: 7 -  10 = -3, not found
j =  7, i =  3: 7 -   2 =  5, not found
j =  8, i =  2: 7 - (-2) = 9, not found
j =  9, i =  1: 7 -   1 =  6, found
j = 10, i =  0: 7 -   0 =  7, not found
```

The first 1 elements have a sum of 1, the last 1 or 6 elements have a sum of 6, so elements 1..9 or 1..4 have a sum of 9. The time is basically n insertions and lookups into a data structure.

Answer (score -1):

Below is what i have done using the sliding window approach. It works for positive and negative numbers in the array. tested for the given input and works. please see if this helps.

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array([1, -3, 4, 8, 2, -14, 3, -1, 10, 6])#np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7])
length=len(arr)
start=0
end=0
sum1=0
flag=False
VALUE=9

while(flag==False):
sum1+=arr[end]
if(sum1<VALUE):
    if(end<length-1):
        end+=1
    else:
        if(start<lenth-1):
            start+=1
            end=start
            sum1=0
        else:
            print("didnt find any range**")
            break
elif(sum1==VALUE):
    print('start',start,'end',end)
    break
else:
    if(start<length-1):
        
        start+=1
        end=start
        sum1=0
      #  print("start",start)
        
    else:
        print("didnt find any range")
        break
```

Comment: Hi, this answer would be better if you explained the algorithm a bit

Comment: Hi @guysherman, thanks for your comment.  I have written this in Python. Basically what it does is : 1)  intialises a sliding window ( start & end to 0) 2) Then it starts with the window. 2) If the window sum is less than  expected given sum it increases the end pointer.  this process is repeated either the sum is met/cross the Sum value or reaches the boundary of the array .  If the sum is reached means we are done. 3) In the other two cases i.e. end is reached/sum is crossed the given value, it shifts the window by incrementing the start pointer. This process is repeated until we cover array

Answer (score -2):

The above posted solutions looks good.  Here is my code for the same.  **It takes O(n) time to complete.**

The output from the above program is 2 4.  Which means 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements sum gives the value of 9.  *2nd Element indicates array index of 1 not 2.*

```
class FindArrayProblem {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int array[] = {1, -3, 4, 8, 2, -14, 3, -1, 10, 6};
        int sum = 9;
        findSubArray(array,sum);
    }

    static void findSubArray(int[] array, int sum){
        int start = 0 , end =0;
        int tmpSum = array[0] ;
        while (end < array.length) {
            if (tmpSum == sum){
                System.out.println((start + 1) + " " + (end + 1)) ;
                break;
            }
            if (tmpSum <= sum){
               end++ ;
                if (end < array.length)
                    tmpSum += array[end];
            } else {
                tmpSum -= array[start];
                ++ start;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you copied a solution for a different problem. What makes you think this will work with negative numbers? For example, take n numbers, the first n-1 equal to 2, the last equal to 3-2n, and try to find the sum 1.

Comment: @gnasher729,
1) there are plenty of such interview questions online.  If you spend few mins coding you'll figure out the answer, good to see that you concluded the code is copied.  
2) The question was to find a first sub-array which this code does, not sure which different problem i solved here.  
3) Regarding the test-case mentioned, i haven't tested that.  If it fails yes, it can be improved to fix.
4) Thanks for downvoting :-)